# Additional drivers for Kubuntu

Tags: drivers

How do I install additional drivers for Kubuntu?  I don't see anything for it in System Settings, and the method given for Ubuntu doesn't seem to apply.

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04 on an HP Pavilion, and my wireless isn't working. According to **lspci**:

`Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 522a (rev 01)`

I assume that the lack of a driver for the 522A is the cause of my problem, since all the other devices have an obvious use.  Furthermore, wireless works on my laptop in later versions of Kubuntu, as well as in 14.04 on a different machine.

Comment: What driver do you need?

Comment: Are you sure that is the wireless device? What I have found on Google is a `Realtke PCIE CardReader with device ID 522A` which seems to be something like a SD card driver...

Comment: Yes, I discovered the same thing but didn't know what to make of it since that was the only unmatched Realtek device.  So how can I determine what the correct Realtek device is, if not from lspci?